# Awk betweens two times in a log file

Tags: bash, awk

I need to find all the strings contained in a certain period of time and I used awk but it doesn't print anything, I'll also leave a string from a log attached as an example

```bash
ctime=$(date '+%H:%M:%S')
 shour=$(date -d "$ctime 5 minutes ago" '+%H:%M:%S')
 ehour=$(date '+%H:%M:%S')

 awk -F '[, ]' -v shour="$shour" -v ctime="$ctime" '$2 >= shour && $2 
 <= ctime {print}' file
```

**Example of log i use "," " " as delimiters:**

*2023-11-13 09:36:28,233    INFO    ete-CUR2OPT:CtO2002 CUR2OPT:AltaCliente:713 MainProcess:Thread-716520   Created client: 3333333333*

The result I expect is that it prints all the lines that contain as hours, minutes and seconds those included between shour and ctime

Comment: Can you please add the expected result?

Comment: It seems to work for me once I've adjusted the time to be in the last 5 minutes ; you can try it here : https://ideone.com/M9Gjhh